# Replace repetitive string in #Python

Tags: python, regex

I have got a super-repetitive string `Lux` that exists in several variables and names such as:
`Luxcomments1718 (df)`, `Luxsub1718 (df)`,`Lux_Num_Comments (df.column)`,and `Luxsub1718.csv (filename)`.
How do I replace all the word `Lux` with another word such as `Tux` without editing them one by one?

```
Luxcomments1718 = df.loc[df.Family_Type == 'Lux']
Luxcomments1718 = Luxcomments1718[Luxcomments1718.Comments.str.contains('|'.join(selection))]
print(len(Luxcomments1718))

df2 = Luxcomments1718.Comments.str.split(expand=True).stack()
df2 = df2[df2.isin(selection)].value_counts()
Luxsub1718 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
Luxsub1718['Lux_Num_Comments']=Luxsub1718[0]
del Luxsub1718[0]
Luxsub1718.to_csv('Luxsub1718.csv')
```

Comment: please provide an example input and output that minimally reproduce your problem and what you expect the solution to be.

Comment: you can easily do it in the interpreter, selecting one word will select all the same.

Comment: @Cyber-Tech how to do it only on selected cells? The Ctrl+H command affects all the words within the entire .ipynb / .py file.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be adding in your file:

```
with open("yourfile.py", "r") as start:
    with open("targetfile.py", "w") as end:
        for line in start:
            end.write(line.replace('Lux', 'Tux'))
```

Note that this creates another file. I don't think there's a way to modify the file itself, beside doing it from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any modern text editor has global change capabilities.  In `vi`, it's `:%s/Lux/Tux/g`; in most of the MS editors, it's the CTRL-h command.
2. Use an external program to effect the change.  In the UNIX family, `sed` is a command-line filter that uses the same `ex` macros as `vi`.
3. Write a simple Python program to `replace('Lux', 'Tux')` on the entire input file.

Comment: I am using Google Collab. The Ctrl+H command allows find and replace for the entire file. How do I do it only on selected cells?

Comment: You need to specify how the cells are selected; this is not part of your original question.  Regardless, the CTRL-f / CTRL-h allows you to "change and find next", starting from the current cursor location.  Simply place the cursor at the top of your cell, get into the change/replace box, and use the change/find button to walk through the cell quickly.